# Ansible: Update a virsh VM

Tags: virtual-machine, ansible

I need to create a playbook to update a VM running in a virsh environment. Steps would be:

1. Backup some contents of a VM (Done)
2. Shutdown the vm
3. Copy the new VM image and XML file
4. Restore backup (just mount the image and untar a file)
5. Start up the new VM

I've created a hosts file with some variables:

```
[virsh-hosts]
host1
host2

[vms]
vm1 hypervisor=host1
vm2 hypervisor=host1
vm3 hypervisor=host2
```

So, for example when updating VM1 I'll need to connect host1, shutdown the VM1, copy the new image and xml file, define it and startup the new VM.

My question is: How can I connect to VM1's hypervisor (through the variable), exec the shutdown, copy the new images and start the new VM?

As far as I know, all the tasks in a playbook are executed in the host being processed, but I need to exec tasks on different hosts (and get the name of that hosts from a variable).

Maybe delegate_to is the solution here or there is some other way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run your play on the `virsh-hosts` group, and loop through the `vms` group with a condition:

```
- hosts: virsh-hosts
  tasks:
    - name: Do something on all vms on this host
      ping:
      when: hostvars[item].hypervisor == inventory_name
      with_items: groups.vms
```

You can also run on the `vms` group and use `delegate_to` like you said:

```
- hosts: vms
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - ping:
      delegate_to: "{{hypervisor}}"
```

The big difference here is the group and host variables available. If you delegate a task, the variables available are still the one of the original machine. That means that even if the task will run on `host1`, host_vars, group_vars and facts will be those of `vm1`.

If you don't need the VM's host/group vars, use `delegate_to` as it allows you to work on several VMs in parallel. You should turn off facts gathering (`gather_facts: no` after the `hosts: vms` line), so ansible wouldn't try to ssh to the VM, which probably will be shut down.

If on top of that you don't have any scenario in which you need to contact the VM at all, you can even have ansible always contact the hypervisor when running a play on the VM by setting `ansible_ssh_host` in the inventory:

```
[vms]
vm1 ansible_ssh_host=host1
```

This saves you the repated `delegate_to` lines.

Comment: thanks! but, any idea why it's trying to connect to the delegated host with the user executing the playbook instead of with the user specified in the variables?

Comment: I found `remote_user: root` does the job :)